# Como definir a cultura em uma WebService WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Tenho uma plicação `WCF` rodando no `IIS` onde a linguagem/cultura do servidor está definida toda em inglês.

Não existe possibilidade de eu alterar as configurações do servidor de modo que pudesse alterar a cultura ou linguagem do mesmo. Precisaria de uma solução a nível de aplicação.

Tentei utilizar no `Web.config` a mesma configuração que se utiliza quando se quer fazer isto para aplicações `ASP.NET` mas aparentemente o `WCF` não lê esta configuração:

```
//Diminuído para brevidade
<configuration> 
    <system.web>  
        <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    <system.web> 
<configuration>
```

Alguém já teve este problema que pode me ajudar a resolver?

Comment: Não conheço a arquitetura de seu sistema, nem sou especialista em WCF para poder formular uma resposta completa... Mas o tratamento de cultura não deveria ser restrito à interface da aplicação? Se não houver mesmo uma forma de configurar isso nas bibliotecas do Communication Foundation, eu até entendo o motivo.

Comment: No caso acima o contexto é a criação de um `WebService`, então não tem uma interface. Seria consumido por uma outra aplicação. Em uma analogia pode considerar uma `API` a ser consumida por outra aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

Caso você use apenas HTTP, você pode ativar a propriedade `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled`, assim o WCF irá ler as configurações do *globalization*.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Isso fará que seu WCF seja executado no mesmo pipeline do ASP.NET, o que impossibilitará de usar outros protocolos que não sejam HTTP.

Mais informações na [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicehostingenvironmentsection.aspnetcompatibilityenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Abrigado pela resposta. Porém adicionando a compatibilidade com `ASP.NET` faz com que muitas mudanças seja feitas. A começar pelo fato do serviço passar por todo o `Pipeline` do `ASP.NET` e neste caso deve haver também perda de desempenho. Mas com certeza esta é a solução para os casos onde se utiliza a compatibilidade.

Comment: Verdade, deve ficar com desempenho pior.

Comment: Acredito que a resposta esteja no `configuration hell` do `WCF`. Mas é sempre complicado mexer alí.

Comment: Já tentou usar    `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");` ?

Comment: Isso funciona Guilherme. Mas estava procurando mesmo uma resposta mais configurável. Entendo que posso colocar algo no `Web.config` e setar neste mesmo código mas acredito que exista alguma solução que vá inteiramente no arquivo de configuração. Sua resposta fica como a melhor qualificada para "V" até agora ;)